Is it known whether or not OEIS sequence A091308 is finite?
OEIS sequence A038395 is defined as the concatenation of the first $n$ odd numbers in reverse order: $1,$ $31,$ $531,$ $7531,$ $97531,$ $1197531,$ etc., and A091308 is the sequence of primes in A038395. The OEIS identifies the first four elements of A091308 as elements a(2), a(37), a(62), and a(409) of A038395, but is silent on whether or not there are any more. What is known of sequence A091308 seems to be entirely the result of brute-force computation. I haven't been able to find any information about it other than the OEIS entry itself and a conjecture by Florentin Smarandache (in Sequences of Numbers Involved in Unsolved Problems) that it contains infinitely many primes. However, he has no discussion to back up the conjecture.

Any information how far this has been checked ? Surely to find another prime , brute force is the only option.

Since $n$ has on the order of $\log(n)$ digits, $A038395(n)$ has on the order of $n \log(n)$ digits.  A "random" number of that size has probability $\sim 1/(n \log(n))$ of being prime.  Since $\sum_n 1/(n \log n)$ diverges, it is reasonable to expect the sequence to have infinitely many primes.  However, because it diverges so slowly, the fifth prime might be out of reach of practical computation.  These are just heuristics, not a proof, but AFAIK there is nothing better available.

Well, I found the fifth prime, $A038395(2717)$ which has $10313$ digits.

@RobertIsrael - First, congrats on finding $A091308(5).$ Can I assume that this will show up at some point in OEIS? :) Regarding the heuristic argument: it's interesting, but I wonder if anything relevant to the question can be inferred from the fact that $A091308(n)$ must have $A091308(n-1)$ as a suffix in its base $10$ representation.

@TedHopp It has been submitted to the editors, and will hopefully show up soon.

@TedHopp You can very easily compute this number :) Concerning your question : Usually , a question like "produces this sequence infinite many primes ?" is completely out of reach , as here. In this case , we can only judge by heuristics , there is nothing better. Sometimes , we expect infinite many entries although none is known !
